# Problem with Containers - React and Styled Components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I did a section and the html tag and body tag is like that

[HTML Tag](http://prntscr.com/oekjel)

[Body Tag](http://prntscr.com/oekklg)
[Section Tag] (http://prntscr.com/oekku9)

Also the section is not getting dimensions

Live Version: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-thunder-mu1ss

I want to make the products be on the center of the center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-ellis-v4m7y)

Basically the issue was in your header component,

On small devices, the nav buttons were not getting stacked, this made the header wider than the screen width.

Fixed the stacking of nav buttons by adding

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Other minor fixes included, removing the large padding  `padding: 6.9rem 31.9rem;` on header and replacing it with 15px padding on small devices

Also removed margin-left of individual nav buttons on small screen

To get the product to be aligned in the center, comment

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    /* align-items: flex-start; */  comment this line 
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

from *product/styles > Container*

This particular line was aligning your products to the left on small devices

Comment: But still not working here, idk why. In devices like S5, it works, but with others, not

Comment: I changed the max-width on media-queries for 450px and now it's working on all devices